# TreeViolationException problem

Tags: java, collections

Hi Im having some trouble when inserting to the right of a node in a binary tree... I just dont see why the exception is happening.  This is the method to inset:

```
public void attachRight(BinaryTree<T> tree) {
    if (right != null) {
        throw new TreeViolationException();

    }
    if (tree != null) {
        tree.parent = this;
        right = tree;
    }
}
```

This is the code in my main class

public class Testing {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*  the tree to be built                30
     *                                    /    \
     *                                  12     16
     *                                 /  \   /  \
     *                               null  1  2   5
     */

    //Create binary tree and set root to 30
    BinaryTree<Integer> root = new BinaryTree<Integer>();
    root.makeRoot(30);
    //System.out.println(root.getData()); //for verifying only

    //Insert 12 -> left(30)
    root.attachLeft(new BinaryTree<Integer>());
    root.left.setData(12);

    //Insert 16 -> right(30)
    root.attachRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>());
    root.right.setData(16);

    //insert 1 -> right(12)
    root.right.attachRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>());
    root.right.right.setData(1);

    //insert 2 -> left(16)
    root.right.attachLeft(new BinaryTree<Integer>());
    root.right.left.setData(2);

    //insert 5 -> right(16)
    root.right.attachRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>());
    root.right.right.setData(5);

    System.out.println(root.getData());
    System.out.println(root.left.getData());
    System.out.println(root.right.getData());

}
```

}

I'm only able to insert, 30, 12, and 16.  Not sure what's going on....
This is the error I get, it happens in the attachRight method

Exception in thread "main" proj5.TreeViolationException
    at proj5.BinaryTree.attachRight(BinaryTree.java:98)

TreeViolationException is just a class that I have that extends RuntimeException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information given, the exception should come from this line:

```
//insert 5 -> right(16)
root.right.attachRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>());
```

because root.right.attachRight() has already been called on this line:

```
//insert 1 -> right(12)
root.right.attachRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>());
```

and root.right already has right node. Why it comes earlier, is impossible to diagnose right now. You should provide more information (e.g. BinaryTree class full implementation).

Comment: I think
//insert 1 -> right(12)
root.right.attachRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>());
should be
//insert 1 -> right(12)
root.left.attachRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>());